# ¿Cómo agrandar el margen del background de un menu html?

Tags: html, ccs

El código es el siguiente y quisiera agregarle más margen, intenté con border:4; pero no resulta. ¿Alguna ayuda? estaría buscando la solución más simple del problema:

```
<html>
    <style>
        .centrado{
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
            -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
            transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            text-align: center;
            background-color: red;
        }
    </style>
    <div class=centrado>
        <a href="wikipedia.org">
            <input type="button" value="wikipedia1" class="boton"/>
        </a>
        <a href="wikipedia.org">
            <input type="button" value="wikipedia2" class="boton"/>
        </a>
    </div>
</html>
```

Saludos y gracias por adelantado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para lo que necesitas puedes utilizar la propiedad de **css**: **padding**. Esto lo que hará será, respetando las dimensiones del contenedor en que se encuentre, dar espacio interior al contenido que albergue. He modificado tu código ligéramente para que puedas ver como queda. También le he dado un poco de "aire" a los botones separándolos un poco para que se vea mejor como queda el contenido con el padding:

```css
        .centrado{
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
            -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
            transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            text-align: center;
            background-color: red;
            padding: 25px; /*línea incluida como ejemplo de uso*/
        }
        .marginPru {margin-top:1em /*incluido para separar los botones entre si*/}
```

```html
    <div class=centrado>
        <a href="wikipedia.org">
            <input type="button" value="wikipedia1" class="boton"/>
        </a>
        <a class="marginPru" href="wikipedia.org">
            <input type="button" value="wikipedia2" class="boton"/>
        </a>
    </div>
```

Además comparto un enlace sobre el uso de esta propiedad por si te fuera de utilidad: [Padding - CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding)

Comment: muchisismas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es dar margen al input debes utilizar la clase que tienes en el input. En este caso tu clase es `boton`.

Por lo tanto, añade esa clase en tu hoja de estilos poniéndole un margin. En tu caso he puesto padding y margin para que veas como queda:

```css
input.boton {
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 7px;
}
.centrado{
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
            -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
            transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            text-align: center;
            background-color: red;
        }
```

```html
<html>
    <div class=centrado>
        <a href="wikipedia.org">
            <input type="button" value="wikipedia1" class="boton"/>
        </a>
        <a href="wikipedia.org">
            <input type="button" value="wikipedia2" class="boton"/>
        </a>
    </div>
</html>
```

Comment: no es mi caso, pero sirve gracias.